# Kendo UI grid subrow

Tags: css, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I need to develop a Kendo grid as the one in the mockup that follow:

[image]

This is simple, but when a special value is selected in one of the select fields, a sort of sub-row must be displayed:

[image]

So, this set of 3 (or 6) fields is what I need to have on every grid row. That means I need to add other rows like this, being able to liveedit them or delete.

I'm wondering what is the best way to reach this (if possibile).

Can I simply define the whole set of fields (with sub-row) as a single grid row then split someway it using CSS or Kendo grid already support this kind of layout?

Comment: You will have an list of data ? Or just this 6 possible fields ?

Comment: @MarcoPalma the number of fields is static, values in the combo cames from remote services but the special value that activate the subrow in fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Kendo UI grid is a widget which allows you to visualize and edit data via its table representation, KendoGrid is not best approach in my opinion.

You just need to create on kendo template, with you 3 static dropsdown's and when you click on your "special" value you will have to append your template again with other data if is needed.

Check on [KendoTemplate docs](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/templates/overview).

EDIT: So you will have to use kendogrid detail (hardcoded), and use tempate to show you 3 fields I think.
Hope this help

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unluckily I think I misunderstood your comment to the question and I gave you bad information. I *still* need the grid widget: as I have a fixed number of fields... on every row, but I still need to add additional row (all of the same kind, with subrow). I edited the question to be more precise.

Comment: I updated my awser, you 'subrow' that you saing I think you can use detail to do it.Or if is not inline edit you can easily use  popup editor.

Comment: Not sure if I can do exactly what excepted but seems really near to my needs. Never heard of grid details before! Thanks.